# Linking Xamarin iOS UI project to Visual Studio projects

Tags: c#, iphone, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to write a simple application for the iPhone using Xamarin. Designing via the Interface Builder is only allowed in Xamarin Studio on the Mac. Is there a way to create the rest of the solution in Visual Studio and connect the projects somehow, or do I have to develop the whole solution in Xamarin Studio to use the Interface Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to initially create the project on the Mac as a storyboard app.  Whenever you edit the storyboard, Xamarin Studio opens Xcode. Once you're done editing the storyboard, you can move it over to Visual Studio in Windows and either add projects to that solution or add the storyboard project to a solution that you already have in Visual Studio.

Whenever you need to make changes to the storyboard file, you need to open the storyboard project on the Mac and make the changes there. Currently I'm manually moving the files around, but I will eventually try to host a shared folder.

Comment: Xcode? or Xamarin on the Mac? Xcode is definitely not an option... we have too large of a C# codebase and need everything to be portable. Doing everything in Xamarin Studio may be possible, but there are pros and cons both ways.

Comment: I am currently facing this problem, will try this solution on editing to xcode/xamarin studio then porting to VS 2012.
Thanks in advance for the answer.